# How to avoid firing itemStateChanged event in JComboBox while typing?

Tags: java, autocomplete, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox which is editable and Autocorrect enabled as follows.

```
        comboForward = new JComboBox();
        comboForward.setEditable(true);
        AutoCompletion ac = new AutoCompletion(this.comboForward);
        comboForward.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //code to run after event fires                     
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }
        });
```

How can I avoid firing this event when user typing inside `comboBox`. Or at least is there a way to detect when user finishes typing. ? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, adding autocomplete only to comboBox editor component will solve the problem. But in this case you have to provide autocomplete list as String `ArrayList`.

```
ComboBoxEditor editor = comboForward.getEditor();
    JTextField textField = (JTextField) editor.getEditorComponent();
    ArrayList<String> autoCompleteList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Object item : comboForward.getItemList()) {
       autoCompleteList.add(item.toString());
    }

   AutoCompletion  autoCompletion = new AutoCompletion(textField, autoCompleteList);
```